# Apache Solr would not start

Tags: solr

Apache Solr would  not start. Keeps throwing the following error

```
    java -jar example/start.jar 


    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
            at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:179)
            at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
            at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
            at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're not inside the example dir, you need to specify the path for `jetty.home`. It may also be a good idea to set the `jetty.logs` option as well:

```
java -Djetty.home=example -Djetty.logs=/tmp -Dsolr.solr.home=example/solr -jar example/start.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the classpath to solr files with -cp

```
java -cp <path> -jar example/start.jar
```

Comment: For me it also worked when I did `cd /path/to/example` and then invoked solr.

Comment: This hasn't worked for me. Probably because when the `-jar` option is used, the `-cp` option is ignored. Quote from the Java manual for the `-jar` option: "When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored."

Comment: Yes. This is true, You should add the dependencies on your jar Manifest.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you've met the requirements:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall

type: cd /opt/apache-solr-1.3.0/example
type: java -jar start.jar
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrOnAmazonEC2